# How to refresh a facebook profile picture from ajax result

Tags: jquery, facebook

I have a div which is being used as a navigation container.
On completion of an ajax request i am refreshing the contents of the div using..nav n

```
$('#NAV').load('includes/nav.ini.php');
```

Within the div i have an image which is dynamically loaded from the facebook graph api.

`<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?= $fid ?>/picture">`

where $fid is the facebook user id.

The image is displayed correctly if you refresh the whole page but it will not appear if i refresh the div its contained in with the .load() method shown above.

why is this? and how can i make the page request the image again?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The graph api image url performs a rapid redirect to a second url, which by default will use http rather than https.  This may be causing a security error, so to eliminate that add the parameter ?return_ssl_resources=true to the request.

Note: the img tag should be closed at the end - `<img ... />`

Comment: You don't use a closing tag for an `img`. Either use `<img src="" />` or `<img src="">`

Comment: Correct, should have been self closing. Facebook apps are almost always xhtml, so the unclosed form is not a good idea.